# Thread creating. I'm overwriting all threads with the last thread

Tags: c

I need to create a thread for each incoming person. It works fine creating a thread for each person. But only the last thread lives. the other ones are somehow overwritten by the last one. what am I doing wrong here?  Do you see anything wrong with this code?

```
  Person *person; 
    DWORD bytesRead;

    while(1)
    {   

        person = (Person *) malloc( sizeof(Person) );
        bytesRead = mailslotRead ( mailbox, &person, sizeof(Person) ); 
        if( bytesRead != 0 )
        {
            list_append( planets, &person );
            threadCreate(personThread, &person );
            Sleep(100);
        }
    }


DWORD WINAPI personThread(Person* person)
{

    MessageBox(0, person->name, "New thread created for:", 0);
    while(1)
    {
        person->age += 1;
        MessageBox(0, person->name, "person aged", 0);
        Sleep(5000);
    }

    MessageBox(0, person->name, "Thread died", 0);
}
```

Comment: Don't cast the return value of `malloc` in `C`.

Comment: @Error404, ok, that's not about `personThread`, see reply from user unwind below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass `&person` to the thread, pass `person`. The variable `person` will be overwritten, and since the threads are accessing the location where `person` lives, they will all access the same data. You really want to pass the *value* of `person`, i.e. the newly allocated memory address, to each newly created thread.

And [please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

**UPDATE**: The code you're showing for `personThread()` fails to treat its argument properly (it should be `void *`, cast to `Person **` and dereferenced) so I think you're also invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: If the OP willes pass `person` to the thread function it shall cast its argument to `Person *`.

Comment: @alk Please read the `malloc()` link for my thoughts about casting pointers to/from `void *` in C.

Comment: I was referring to the cast necessary inside the thread function.